# MikTex Console is opening with error

Tags: errors, miktex

Whenever I open MikTex Console it pops up with an error and then I have to exit the application and try again but to no avail.
[image: Error popup]

[image: Error]

[image: Error message]

I clicked on Copy info and here is the error: GENERAL MIKTEX INFORMATION
ReportDate: 2021-08-11 20:56:45
CurrentVersion: 21.8
SetupDate: 2021-08-11 18:50:00
SetupVersion: 21.6
Configuration: Regular
GitInfo: 30e6b49 / 2021-08-06 15:45:04
OS: Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit, build 19042
SharedSetup: no
LinkTargetDirectory: C:\Users\Home-T410\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64
PathOkay: yes
LastUpdateCheck: 2021-08-11 18:50:51
LastUpdate: 2021-08-11 18:51:32
LastUpdateDb: 2021-08-11 18:50:45
SystemAdmin: yes
RootPrivileges: no
AdminMode: no
Root0: C:\Users\Home-T410\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX
Root1: C:\Users\Home-T410\AppData\Local\MiKTeX
Root2: C:\Users\Home-T410\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
UserInstall: C:\Users\Home-T410\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
UserConfig: C:\Users\Home-T410\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX
UserData: C:\Users\Home-T410\AppData\Local\MiKTeX
Invokers: non-existing/explorer

ERROR DETAILS
Program: miktex-console
Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\MD5\MD5.cpp:85
Error: C:\jenkins\workspace\miktex\windows\build\source\Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\MD5\MD5.cpp:85: internal error

Comment: the miktex bug tracker is here: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues

Comment: If all else fails, uninstalling and reinstalling MikTeX is an option.